# Word js : matchCase search option is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins, paragraph, office-online-server

I am trying to search a word which is initial caps but matchCase search option is not working as expected. below is my code :

```
textToHighlight = "Deed";
var rangeCol = para.search(textToHighlight, { matchCase: true});
```

Paragraph Text : Seller shall convey title to the Property to Buyer by grant deed in the form of letter("Deed").

It always returns first instance of deed which is non caps.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need a `regex` that will take in acount the whole word inside `""`.

Answer (score 0):

See the snippet below, it's working as expected. Are you trying to do something else?

```js
let para = "[...] to Buyer by grant deed in the form of letter"

textToHighlight = "Deed";
var rangeCol = para.search(textToHighlight, { matchCase: true});

console.log(rangeCol); // -1, not found

para = "[...] to Buyer by grant Deed in the form of letter"

textToHighlight = "Deed";
var rangeCol = para.search(textToHighlight, { matchCase: true});
console.log(rangeCol); // 24, found
```

In terms of highlighting the text with vanilla JavaScript, I've come up with the following:

```js
let _text = text.innerText;
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  text.innerText = _text;
  let textToHighlight = input.value;
  var rangeCol = text.innerText.search(textToHighlight, {
    matchCase: true,
  });

  let node = text.childNodes[0];
  let spaces = node.textContent.match(/^\s*/)[0].length;

  let range = new Range();
  range.setStart(node, spaces + rangeCol);
  range.setEnd(node, spaces + rangeCol + textToHighlight.length);

  const mark = document.createElement("mark");
  range.surroundContents(mark);
});
```

```css
#text {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

mark {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="text">
  Seller shall convey title to the Property to Buyer by grant deed in the form of letter("Deed").
</div>
<input id="input" type="text" />
<button id="button">Highlight</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Luis! problem is when I try to select that returned range which highlights first instance, not the actual instance which is initial caps
'''
rangeCol.items[winstance].select();
'''

Comment: Could you please share your highlighting code? I think the problem is not with `search()`

Comment: `typeof rangeCol === "number"`, you cannot do `rangeCol.items[winstance].select();`

Comment: '
var rangeCol = para.search(textToHighlight, { matchCase: true });
     para.context.load(rangeCol);
     return para.context.sync().then(function () {
      rangeCol.items[winstance].font.color = 'blue';
      rangeCol.items[winstance].select();
      para.context.sync().then(function () {
       q.resolve();
      })
     })
'

Comment: here, winstance = 0 because it has only one Deed which is initial caps